# How do you fit a tf.Dataset to a Keras Autoencoder Model when the Dataset has been generated using TFX?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tfx

### Problem

As the title suggests I have been trying to create a pipeline for training an Autoencoder model using TFX. The problem I'm having is fitting the tf.Dataset returned by the `DataAccessor.tf_dataset_factory` object to the Autoencoder.

Below I summarise the steps I've taken through this project, and have some Questions at the bottom if you wish to skip the background information.

### Intro

#### TFX Pipeline

The TFX components I have used so far have been:

- CsvExampleGenerator (the dataset has 82 columns, all numeric, and the sample csv has 739 rows)
- StatisticsGenerator / SchemaGenerator, the schema has been edited as is now loaded in using an Importer
- Transform
- Trainer (this is the component I am currently having problems with)

#### Model

The model that I am attempting to train is based off of the example laid out here https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/autoencoder. However, my model is being trained on tabular data, searching for anomalous results, as opposed to image data.

As I have tried a couple of solutions I have tried using both the Keras.layers and Keras.model format for defining the model and I outline both below:

###### Subclassing Keras.Model

```
class Autoencoder(keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self, features):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
        
        self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
            keras.layers.Dense(82, activation = 'relu'),
            keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = 'relu'),
            keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu'),
            keras.layers.Dense(8, activation = 'relu')
        ])
        
        self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
            keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu'),
            keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = 'relu'),
            keras.layers.Dense(len(features), activation = 'sigmoid')
        ])

    def call(self, x):
        inputs = [keras.layers.Input(shape = (1,), name = f) for f in features]
        dense = keras.layers.concatenate(inputs)
        
        encoded = self.encoder(dense)
        decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
    
        return decoded
```

###### Subclassing Keras.Layers

```
def _build_keras_model(features: List[str]) -> tf.keras.Model:
    inputs = [keras.layers.Input(shape = (1,), name = f) for f in features]
    dense = keras.layers.concatenate(inputs)

    dense = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = 'relu')(dense)
    dense = keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu')(dense)
    dense = keras.layers.Dense(8, activation = 'relu')(dense)
    dense = keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu')(dense)
    dense = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = 'relu')(dense)
    outputs = keras.layers.Dense(len(features), activation = 'sigmoid')(dense)
    
    model = keras.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = outputs)
    model.compile(
        optimizer = 'adam',
        loss = 'mae'
    )

    return model
```

#### TFX Trainer Component

For creating the Trainer Component I have been mainly following the implementation details laid out here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/trainer

As well as following the default penguins example: https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/tfx/penguin_simple#write_model_training_code

###### run_fn defintion

```
def run_fn(fn_args: tfx.components.FnArgs) -> None:
    tft_output = tft.TFTransformOutput(fn_args.transform_output)
    
    train_dataset = _input_fn(
        file_pattern = fn_args.train_files,
        data_accessor = fn_args.data_accessor,
        tf_transform_output = tft_output,
        batch_size = fn_args.train_steps
    )

    eval_dataset = _input_fn(
        file_pattern = fn_args.eval_files,
        data_accessor = fn_args.data_accessor,
        tf_transform_output = tft_output,
        batch_size = fn_args.custom_config['eval_batch_size']
    )

#   model = Autoencoder(
#       features = fn_args.custom_config['features']
#   )
    model = _build_keras_model(features = fn_args.custom_config['features'])
        
    model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mse')
    
    model.fit(
        train_dataset,
        steps_per_epoch = fn_args.train_steps,
        validation_data = eval_dataset,
        validation_steps = fn_args.eval_steps
    )
    
    ...
```

###### _input_fn definition

```
def _apply_preprocessing(raw_features, tft_layer):
    transformed_features = tft_layer(raw_features)
    return transformed_features

def _input_fn(
    file_pattern,
    data_accessor: tfx.components.DataAccessor,
    tf_transform_output: tft.TFTransformOutput,
    batch_size: int) -> tf.data.Dataset:
    """
    Generates features and label for tuning/training.
      Args:
        file_pattern: List of paths or patterns of input tfrecord files.
        data_accessor: DataAccessor for converting input to RecordBatch.
        tf_transform_output: A TFTransformOutput.
        batch_size: representing the number of consecutive elements of returned
          dataset to combine in a single batch
      Returns:
        A dataset that contains features where features is a
          dictionary of Tensors.
    """
    dataset = data_accessor.tf_dataset_factory(
        file_pattern,
        tfxio.TensorFlowDatasetOptions(batch_size = batch_size),
        tf_transform_output.transformed_metadata.schema
     )
    
    transform_layer = tf_transform_output.transform_features_layer()
    def apply_transform(raw_features):
        return _apply_preprocessing(raw_features, transform_layer)
    
    return dataset.map(apply_transform).repeat()
```

This differs from the _input_fn example given above as I was following the example in the next tfx tutorial found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/tfx/penguin_tft#run_fn

Also for reference, there is no Target within the example data so there is no `label_key` to be passed to the `tfxio.TensorFlowDatasetOptions` object.

#### Error

When trying to run the Trainer component using a TFX `InteractiveContext` object I receive the following error.

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense_460/kernel:0', 'dense_460/bias:0', 'dense_461/kernel:0', 'dense_461/bias:0', 'dense_462/kernel:0', 'dense_462/bias:0', 'dense_463/kernel:0', 'dense_463/bias:0', 'dense_464/kernel:0', 'dense_464/bias:0', 'dense_465/kernel:0', 'dense_465/bias:0'].
```

From my own attempts to solve this I believe the problem lies in the way that an Autoencoder is trained. From the Autoencoder example linked here https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/autoencoder the data is fitted like so:

```
autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=10,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test))
```

therefore it stands to reason that the tf.Dataset should also mimic this behaviour and when testing with plain Tensor objects I have been able to recreate the error above and then solve it when adding the target to be the same as the training data in the .fit() function.

#### Things I've Tried So Far

###### Duplicating Train Dataset

```
    model.fit(
        train_dataset,
        train_dataset,
        steps_per_epoch = fn_args.train_steps,
        validation_data = eval_dataset,
        validation_steps = fn_args.eval_steps
    )
```

Raises error due to Keras not accepting a 'y' value when a dataset is passed.

```
ValueError: `y` argument is not supported when using dataset as input.
```

###### Returning a dataset that is a tuple with itself

```
def _input_fn(...


    dataset = data_accessor.tf_dataset_factory(
        file_pattern,
        tfxio.TensorFlowDatasetOptions(batch_size = batch_size),
        tf_transform_output.transformed_metadata.schema
     )
    
    transform_layer = tf_transform_output.transform_features_layer()
    def apply_transform(raw_features):
        return _apply_preprocessing(raw_features, transform_layer)
    
    dataset = dataset.map(apply_transform)
    
    return dataset.map(lambda x: (x, x))
```

This raises an error where the keys from the features dictionary don't match the output of the model.

```
ValueError: Found unexpected keys that do not correspond to any Model output: dict_keys(['feature_string', ...]). Expected: ['dense_477']
```

At this point I switched to using the keras.model Autoencoder subclass and tried to add output keys to the Model using an output which I tried to create dynamically in the same way as the inputs.

```
    def call(self, x):
        inputs = [keras.layers.Input(shape = (1,), name = f) for f in x]
        dense = keras.layers.concatenate(inputs)
        
        encoded = self.encoder(dense)
        decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
    
        outputs = {}
        for feature_name in x:
            outputs[feature_name] = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(decoded)

        return outputs
```

This raises the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert a symbolic Keras input/output to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a symbolic value to a NumPy call, which is not supported. Or, you may be trying to pass Keras symbolic inputs/outputs to a TF API that does not register dispatching, preventing Keras from automatically converting the API call to a lambda layer in the Functional Model.
```

I've been looking into solving this issue but am no longer sure if the data is being passed correctly and am beginning to think I'm getting side-tracked from the actual problem.

#### Questions

- Has anyone managed to get an Autoencoder working when connected via TFX examples?
- Did you alter the tf.Dataset or handled the examples in a different way to the _input_fn demonstrated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I managed to find an answer to this and wanted to leave what I found here in case anyone else stumbles onto a similar problem.

It turns out my feelings around the error were correct and the solution did indeed lie in how the tf.Dataset object was presented.

This can be demonstrated when I ran some code which simulated the incoming data using randomly generated tensors.

```py
tensors = [tf.random.uniform(shape = (1, 82)) for i in range(739)]
# This gives us a list of 739 tensors which hold 1 value for 82 'features' simulating the dataset I had

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tensors)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x : (x, x))
# This returns a dataset which marks the training set and target as the same
# which is what the Autoecnoder model is looking for

model.fit(dataset ...)
```

Following this I proceeded to do the same thing with the dataset returned by the _input_fn. Given that the tfx DataAccessor object returns a features_dict however I needed to combine the tensors in that dict together to create a single tensor.

This is how my _input_fn looks now:

```py
def create_target_values(features_dict: Dict[str, tf.Tensor]) -> tuple:
    value_tensor = tf.concat(list(features_dict.values()), axis = 1)
    return (features_dict, value_tensor)

def _input_fn(
    file_pattern,
    data_accessor: tfx.components.DataAccessor,
    tf_transform_output: tft.TFTransformOutput,
    batch_size: int) -> tf.data.Dataset:
    """
    Generates features and label for tuning/training.
      Args:
        file_pattern: List of paths or patterns of input tfrecord files.
        data_accessor: DataAccessor for converting input to RecordBatch.
        tf_transform_output: A TFTransformOutput.
        batch_size: representing the number of consecutive elements of returned
          dataset to combine in a single batch
      Returns:
        A dataset that contains (features, target_tensor) tuple where features is a
          dictionary of Tensors, and target_tensor is a single Tensor that is a concatenated tensor of all the
          feature values.
    """
    dataset = data_accessor.tf_dataset_factory(
        file_pattern,
        tfxio.TensorFlowDatasetOptions(batch_size = batch_size),
        tf_transform_output.transformed_metadata.schema
    )
    
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: create_target_values(features_dict = x))
    return dataset.repeat()
```

Comment: Im running into similar situations here. Except my dataset is a different shape and dtypes so I can't run `tf.concat` like what you're doing here. Any suggestions?

Comment: So I don't think `tf.concat` is the necessary part of this solution, that just happened to be what I used. 
It's difficult to say for sure without knowing more about your specific issues but I would say focusing on a mapping function like `create_target_values` is would be the best thing.
It would probably be a good idea to experiment outside of TFX as well using just the basic Dataset object like I do above and then you can apply your findings with the tfx `_input_fn`

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. Spent the afternoon failing with a similar issue. This line was critical to me: dataset = dataset.map(lambda x : (x, x)). Other shaping issues too, but the break through was to map :-)