# Concatenate tensors of different rank into a single tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I'm looking to feed an autoencoder my features, as both training and target data. Majority of the features have rank 1; are a single column of values like [1,2,3,4]. Some have been put through one hot encoding so the tensors are of rank 2 and have X columns, with X being the number of categorical values in the one hot encoder, so something like:

```
['a', 'a, 'b', c'] -> [[1,0,0], [1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1]]
```

For some reason keras's `Model.fit` don't accept `y` values if the training data are generators or datasets. So I have to provide my training data as a tuple of `(features, targets)`, and in this case `targets=features`, but at the same time, `features` is a dictionary of tensors so I must concatenate all of the tensors in `features` into a single tensor.

I can do `tf.concat` across all of my feature columns except the one-hot encoded columns, which have rank 2 (instead of 1). How can I somehow turn the one-hot encoded features in X individual tensors and then concat them together?

---

Same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69131245/7242490) where the OP solved his issue using `tf.concat`, but I can't do that here.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to comment your question to ask for a couple of details, but I can't do that because I don't have reputation score (I am new to stack overflow and this is my first post ever). So I will try to explain based on what I understood of your problem - hope it helps.

You can use Pandas to hot-encode your categorical features.

**Example Dataset**

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np

dataset = {'feature_A': np.random.randint(10, size=10),
           'feature_B': np.random.randint(10, size=10),
           'feature_C': np.random.randint(10, size=10),
           'categorical_feature': np.array([chr(97 + random.randint(0, 2)) for i in range(10)])}

print(dataset)

{'feature_A': array([6, 8, 2, 0, 4, 8, 6, 4, 3, 8]),
 'feature_B': array([0, 6, 8, 6, 7, 3, 4, 6, 1, 6]),
 'feature_C': array([0, 7, 7, 3, 7, 4, 0, 3, 2, 7]),
 'categorical_feature': array(['a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c'], dtype='<U1')}
```

**Pandas DataFrame**

Transform the dataset into a Pandas DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
print(df)

   Feature_A  Feature_B  Feature_C Categorical_Feature
0          1          9          9                   e
1          9          9          8                   c
2          5          8          3                   c
3          3          5          7                   c
4          9          8         10                   d
5          6          9          6                   c
6          1          4          5                   d
7          9          5          2                   e
8          3          9          2                   c
9          3          8         10                   a
```

**One-hot & concatenate**

One-hot encode the categorical features and concatenate to the main DataFrame (and drop original categorical feature column)

```
df = pd.concat((df, pd.get_dummies(df['categorical_feature'])), axis=1).drop('categorical_feature', axis=1)

print(df)

   feature_A  feature_B  feature_C  a  b  c
0          0          0          1  0  0  1
1          5          7          0  0  0  1
2          9          2          6  0  1  0
3          1          1          4  0  0  1
4          5          8          8  0  0  1
5          9          1          8  1  0  0
6          5          6          8  1  0  0
7          9          5          0  1  0  0
8          9          4          5  1  0  0
9          8          3          5  1  0  0
```

**NumPy array**

Then you can simply get the values of the DataFrame as a numpy array by using the attribute `.values`. Each row now is one training example that comprises of all the value features + the categorical features as hot encoded vector.

You can use the numpy array directly into your model or, if you wish, you can also transform it into tensorflow tensor by using `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`.

```
dataset = df.values

print(dataset)

array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [5, 7, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [9, 2, 6, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 4, 0, 0, 1],
       [5, 8, 8, 0, 0, 1],
       [9, 1, 8, 1, 0, 0],
       [5, 6, 8, 1, 0, 0],
       [9, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [9, 4, 5, 1, 0, 0],
       [8, 3, 5, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: This is panda frame. I'm referring to tensors in tensorflow.

Comment: Can you please expand a little more in your question and put the errors you are getting? From your question it was not clear if you wanted to concatenate your tensors in the data pipeline or inside the model. If it's inside the model, you need to flatten your rank 2 tensors before concatenating. If it's in the data pipeline, you may want to use ragged tensors if you want to concatenate rank 1 with rank 2 tensors.
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor